# TwoWay Data Binding with MVVM Light on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, mvvm-light

I'm trying to create a custom Button with `ListPickerFlyout` using MVVM. The result that i wanna reach is something like that:

[custom Button with ListPickerFlyout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccino.png)

My problem is how to bind the `SelectedItem` from `ListPickerFlyout` to the content `TextBlock`.

I'm using MVVM Light Windows Phone 8.1 (Store Appp).

My Xaml code:

```
<Button Background="White"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- Content TextBlock -->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyVM.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                Style="{StaticResource DefaultTextBlock}"
                FontSize="22"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"/>

    <Image Height="20"  Grid.Column="1"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Source="../Assets/icons/arrow_down.png"/>
</Grid>

<Button.Flyout>
    <ListPickerFlyout PickerFlyoutBase.Title="$Items$"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding MyVM.listItems}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding MyVM.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" >
        <ListPickerFlyout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                                Style="{StaticResource DefaultTextBlock}"
                                FontSize="22"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListPickerFlyout.ItemTemplate>
    </ListPickerFlyout>
</Button.Flyout>
```

And in MyVM i have

```
public string SelectedItem { get; set; }
```

---

Edit:

Solved the problem, i forgot to add `RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");`.

So, in my MVVM class:

```
private string _selectedItem;
public string SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedItem != value)
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears you've done that.  How are you setting SelectedItem?  What do you expect to be in the text block?  What is in the text block when you run your application?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Diego. Please  follow the tagging guidelines found at http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging and do not force tags into your question title, unless they are a natural part of the title. I've edited your question title into a more natural form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to add the `RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");` in MVVM class.

The complete code:

```
private string _selectedItem;
public string SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedItem != value)
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }
}
```